# SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument - Plotly

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have checked several article to help me correct the following codes but despite changes I don't know how to fix it.
thank you for your help

```
import plotly.graph_objects as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go


x = ['18-25', '25-35', '35-45','45-55','55-65']

plot = px.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
    name = 'Bulle de Babel',
    x = x,
    y = [97,204,192,145,96]
   ),
                         go.Bar(
    name = 'Maniet',
    x = x,
    y = [30,73,85,80,43],
                               go.Bar(
    name = 'iPhone',
    x = x,
    y = [165,127,143,107,86],
                                     go.Bar(
    name = 'hey',
    x = x,
    y = [115,99,92,92,31],
                                           go.Bar(
    name = 'usg',
    x = x,
    y = [64,59,51,29,23])
                                         
plot.update_layout(barmode='stack')    
colors = ['#FDCCFF', '#0F22FA','#D73E0F','#ffd700','#707070']    
plot.show()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Its probably a missing closing bracket `]`

Comment: I think you're missing some closing brackets on some of the `go.Bar` calls

Comment: It would be easier to see if you adjusted your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you currently have, with only the indentation and whitespace adjusted to something more conventional

```
plot = px.Figure(data=[
           go.Bar(
               name='Bulle de Babel',
               x=x,
               y=[97, 204, 192, 145, 96]
           ),
           go.Bar(
               name='Maniet',
               x=x,
               y=[30, 73, 85, 80, 43],
           go.Bar(
               name='iPhone',
               x=x,
               y=[165, 127, 143, 107, 86],
           go.Bar(
               name='hey',
               x=x,
               y=[115, 99, 92, 92, 31],
           go.Bar(
               name='usg',
               x=x,
               y=[64, 59, 51, 29, 23])
```

The *parser* doesn't care about formatting; it easily sees that there is a problem. With this indentation, though, *we* can also more easily see that you have a number of problems:

1. Only the first (and last) call to `go.Bar` has the necessary `)` to finish the function call.
2. There is no `]` to close the list used as the `data` keyword argument.
3. There is no `)` to finished the call to `px.Figure`.

Missing `)`s for `go.Bar` calls aside, I think you got tripped up by the fact that both the last call to `go.Bar` and the call to `px.Figure` would end with *separate* `])` digraphs, and you conflated them into one. A correct code would be

```
plot = px.Figure(data=[
           go.Bar(
               name='Bulle de Babel',
               x=x,
               y=[97, 204, 192, 145, 96]
           ),
           go.Bar(
               name='Maniet',
               x=x,
               y=[30, 73, 85, 80, 43]
           ), # fixed
           go.Bar(
               name='iPhone',
               x=x,
               y=[165, 127, 143, 107, 86]
           ),  #fixed
           go.Bar(
               name='hey',
               x=x,
               y=[115, 99, 92, 92, 31]
           ), # fixed
           go.Bar(
               name='usg',
               x=x,
               y=[64, 59, 51, 29, 23])
       ])  # fixed
```

Comment: Normally, I would simply vote to close as a typo, but I thought this question made for a good example of how  using conventional indentation and whitespace makes it easier to catch syntax errors.